# Why are my ulimit settings ignored in the shell?

Tags: linux, shell, ulimit

I have to execute a .jar, and I need to use ulimit before this execution, so I wrote a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ulimit -S -c unlimited
/usr/java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/java -jar /home/update.jar
```

But the ulimit seems to be ignored, because I have this error :

> java.lang.InternalError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/ext/localedata.jar (Too many open files)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the maximum open files you need to use `ulimit -n`.

Example:

```
ulimit -n 8192
```

The `-c` option is changing the core file size (core dumps), not the maximum open files.

You need to apply the ulimit to the shell that will call the java application.

Comment: I have this error :  ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted

Comment: You need to be root to change the max open files limit.

Comment: You can use `sudo` to call the script that contains the `ulimit` inside (your script). Otherwise, you setup new limits under the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file for you user, so you won't need to run the script as root.